# asynchronous equivilent to array.some() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, module

i need to iterate over a collection checking if each exists as a row in my database

is there a .some() async equivalent for aggregating results of an async true/false check across a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `async` module and specifically this method `async.each` https://github.com/caolan/async#each

https://www.npmjs.com/package/async here's the npm package

Added a small example (instead of my `if` you would want to check in your DB)

```
var tests = ['a', 'b'];
async.each(tests, function(test, callback) {

  if(test === 'c') {
    return callback('We cannot have a c')
  }

  return callback();
}, function(err){
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      // All processing will now stop.
      console.log('C was found');
    } else {
      console.log('All Tests are ok');
    }
});
```